# Can I ask for recommendations for a place in a picture?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

[Where can I find this red sunset in winter, with snow and evergreen trees?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157097) and [Where can I find similar vista from hotel room like Costa Rica looking out Whale Tail National Park?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157100) were closed as "opinion-based". Can't I ask for recommendations here pls?

Answer (score 8):

A general rule for all Stack Exchange sites is that we do not do recommendations.
Besides, all questions are supposed to have one 'right' answer or at least a small number of good answers and your questions could generate long list of locations and no good way to compare them to your photo to select a right answer out of them.

So it was right that these questions were closed.